# Sinatra outputs correctly to console, but no output to browser

Tags: ruby, rss, sinatra

I want to output RSS via Sinatra. I wrote below code, but it outputs nothing. Strangly, when I wrote `puts` before `rss`, it output rss correctly to console! Why I cannot output to browser?

```
#encoding: utf-8

require 'sinatra'
require 'rss'

...

get '/' do

  ...


  rss = RSS::Maker.make("2.0") do |rss|
    rss.channel.about = 'http://hoge/rss.xml'
    rss.channel.title = "hoge"

    ...

  end

  content_type = 'application/xml'  
  # puts rss # => output correctly to console
  rss # => output nothing
end
```

whole code: https://github.com/weed/p120905-rss-process-test/blob/master/app.rb

Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't seem to know what to do with the RSS object.

How about changing the last line in the get block to

```
rss.to_s
```